# ¿Cómo unificar fragmento de código en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

Tengo el siguiente código PHP/Laravel:

```
use App\Models\Fixture;

Fixture::updateOrcreate(['id' => $match['fixture']['id']], [
    'id'      => $match['fixture']['id'],
    'date'    => $match['fixture']['date'],
    'home_id' => $match['teams']['home']['id'],
    'away_id' => $match['teams']['away']['id'],
    'winner'  => NULL
]);
```

Funciona perfectamente, pero a medida que mi proyecto ha crecido me he encontrado con un problema, y es que estoy usando exactamente ese mismo código en 5 controladores diferentes (y creciendo). Mi pregunta es si existe una forma de unificar este fragmento de código para llamarlo desde muchos controladores, de este modo si quiero modificar algo de este solo sea modificarlo una única vez sin necesidad de buscar todos sus llamados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que podrías hacer, es crear un [`trait`](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/traits.html) y ahí una función, por ejemplo `updateFixture()` que llamarás en cualquier controlador.

Para crear un `trait` puedes crear una carpeta adentro de `Models` (O en otra carpeta adentro de app, por ejemplo "app/Traits/"), por lo regular yo la llamo `Utilities` y ahí creas un archivo con extensión `.php`, por ejemplo "MyTrait.php"

La estructura mínima de un `trait` es la siguiente:

```
// Ruta del archivo: app/Traits/MyTrait.php
// Indicas el namespace con la carpeta que contiene tu trait
namespace App\Traits;

// Si usas algún modelo lo agregas aquí
use App\Models\Fixture;

// Es importante que incluyas la palabra clave trait
// El nombre coincide con el nombre del archivo
trait MyTrait
{
    // Creas una función, por ejemplo
    public function updateFixture()
    {
        Fixture::updateOrcreate(['id' => $match['fixture']['id']], [
            'id'      => $match['fixture']['id'],
            'date'    => $match['fixture']['date'],
            'home_id' => $match['teams']['home']['id'],
            'away_id' => $match['teams']['away']['id'],
            'winner'  => NULL
        ]);
    }
}
```

Ahora, esto lo puedes utilizar en tus controladores de la siguiente forma:

```
// app/Http/Controllers/AlgunControlador.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

// Ruta de tu trait
use App\Traits\MyTrait;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    // Debes indicar los trait que vas a utilizar
    use MyTrait;

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // Puedes utilizar el método de esta forma.
        $this->updateFixture();
    }
}
```

Comment: ¡Es exactamente lo que necesitaba! Muchísimas gracias por tu aporte

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!